# Date Comparison using shared preference in android not working

Tags: java, android

In my project I have two activities:

1. Redeem Activity
2. Block Activity

In My

**Redeem Activity**

Well in this app what i want to do is whenever a user click **Redeem** Button today's **date** value will be stored in **shared preferences**.Now whenever he the user tries to launch this app again **Redeem Activity** will compare **today's date**  with  **shared preference date** value.

If **today's date** which i stored in variable **a** == to  **shared preference value**

Then i want to send person to **Block activity** so he can't access **redeem activity** till next day

Now According to my code I got successful in saving date value in shared preference

but problem is i even wrote a **comparing function**(**checkstatus()**) below is the code

```
  private void checkStatus(){
        //comparison and locking activity
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("log",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String saveddate = sharedPref.getString("date","");

        if(a.equals(saveddate)){
            Intent Intent = new Intent(Redeem.this,Block.class);
            startActivity(Intent);
        }
    }
```

but on launching app again even though **values of date are same** still **Redeem Activity** is opening **Intent is not working** and I don't know why.

I am getting this errors now:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.packagenamek/com.packagename.Redeem}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
>   reference

Below is my Code **Redeem.java**

```
 package com.packagename;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Date;

public class Redeem extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView,displaysp;
    Button redeem,displaydate;
    Date date;
    String a;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_redeem);
        checkStatus();
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);
        redeem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.redeem);

        date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

        a = date.toString();
        textView.setText(a);

        //let see saved value

        displaysp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label1);
        redeem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndisplay);







    }

    public void saveInfo(View view){
        //Writing date into Shared Preference
        SharedPreferences sharedPref =getSharedPreferences("log", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("date",a);
        editor.apply();

        Toast.makeText(this,"Redeem Request In Process",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void displayDate(View view){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("log",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String saveddate = sharedPref.getString("date","");



        displaysp.setText(saveddate);
    }

    private void checkStatus(){
        //comparison and locking activity
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("log",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String saveddate = sharedPref.getString("date","");

        if(a.equals(saveddate)){
            Intent Intent = new Intent(Redeem.this,Block.class);
            startActivity(Intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Redeem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.packagename.Redeem">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="130dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="196dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="134dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="Display"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="130dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="352dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="121dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnredeem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="95dp"
        android:onClick="saveInfo"
        android:text="redeem"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/label"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/label"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btndisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="displayDate"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/label"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `checkStatus(); ... a = ...` obviosuly `a` is null

Comment: @Selvin bro i read that but i didn't got the solution the problem is date comparison not working.

Comment: Move `checkStatus();` under the `...textView.setText(a);`

Comment: Thank you btw can u resolve this error too I tried that my null pointer error was gone  also but still  intent is not working i don't know why.Redeem Activity still opening even when both date value same

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `checkStatus()` after initialising the String variable `a`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_redeem);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);
    redeem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.redeem);

    date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

    a = date.toString();
    //checkStatus called after initialising a
    checkStatus();
    textView.setText(a);

    //let see saved value

    displaysp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label1);
    redeem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndisplay);
}



private void checkStatus(){
    //comparison and locking activity
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("log",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String saveddate = sharedPref.getString("date","");

    if(a.contentEquals(saveddate)){
        Intent Intent = new Intent(Redeem.this,Block.class);
        startActivity(Intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro i tried that and  error was gone but date comparison that is checkStatus() function not working.Still  redeem activity opening even when Both value's are equal It should fire an intent to block activity but it is not happening i don't know why

Comment: you can use `contentEquals()` in place of `equals()` for comparing Strings

Comment: I tried that also but intent is not working i don't know why.Redeem Activity still opening even when both date value same